# How to maintain the division value without changing the output resolution

Tags: java

When you add a number to a division product, the precision changes and the output becomes inaccurate
Example:
1/(0.2352941176470588235294117647058823530)=4.2499999999999999999999999999999999989
But the output gave me an approximate value
2.25
I want the value not to change and remain without a round

Thank you

Comment: Well, it's not that exactly, the decimal expansion of `1/(0.2352941176470588235294117647058823530)` is non-terminating.

Comment: How to stop rounding

Comment: Floating point calculations are not exact in many languages, Java included.  What precision do you actually want here?

Comment: The entire number without losing any decimal number

Comment: You can't represent arbitrary real numbers in a computer program. This can be mathematically demonstrated. If your input was a fraction and not `0.23529...`, then you could use rational numbers (which can be represented with absolute accuracy). But if you need real numbers, you're going to have to settle for floating-point approximations.